# How to enable pdo_sqlsrv for php 8.0 run on windows server 2012 R2 IIS?

Tags: php, iis, sql-server-2012, php-8

Actauly I am a now comming here and new comming to PHP.

I want to create a system in php and connect to sql server 2012 remotely. My php version is 8.0

This is my php connection code in connection.php file:

```
<?php
$hostname ="sqlsrv:server=IP remote server; Database=WebAPI";
$Username ="sa";
$PWD ="12345";
try{
    
    $conn = new PDO($hostname, $Username, $PWD);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    echo "Connected";
}catch(PDOException $er){
    echo $er;
}
?>
```

And here is my config in php.ini files.

```
[PHP_PDO_SQLSRV]
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
```

And below is my error:

```
PDOException: could not find driver in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebAPI\Backend\includes\connection.php:22 Stack trace: #0
```

I tried to handled with many blogs on google and it is nothing answered to me. Maybe I am so young on PHP & IIS.

Almost I found on Google were mentioned to PHP 5 but now I am using php 8.0

More image I drop to google drive https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pGcirLpRSYNDCLpP6jDOBsJQKswWjHkV?usp=sharing

Anyone know please help to point out my issue?

I tried this for 2 days but nothing solved. I am first time dev on PHP and IIS.

Comment: Does your project work locally? Or does it only appear when it is published on iis?

Comment: The SQL Server driver isn't shipped with official PHP packages, so you will probably need to install it separately. The exact details of how depend on how you've installed PHP, but the [Readme in their official code repository](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql#readme) links to various useful resources.